# TFS 2008 Custom Work Item State & Triage

Tags: team-foundation-server

I want to add a new work item State & Triage to all/bug work items. I searched Google but can't find anything useful if anyone knows how to do it please let me know.

I know it has something to do with the process template but I can't find the area where I can add these two pieces of information?

Any Help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to export the work item template from Team Foundation Server. To do this start Visual Studio command line and enter this command:

```
witexport /f "File Path\task.xml" /t "TFS name" /p WITLab /n Bug
```

Now you have the Work Item definition on you local machine. Open the file in your favorite XML editor and find this location in the file:

```
<FIELD name="Triage" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Triage" type="String" reportable="dimension">
  <HELPTEXT>Status of triaging the bug</HELPTEXT>
  <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
    <LISTITEM value="Approved" />
    <LISTITEM value="Investigate" />
  </ALLOWEDVALUES>
</FIELD>
```

This is the Triage section for the Bug Work Item. This is where you need to add the new sections that we need.

```
<FIELD name="Triage" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Triage" type="String" reportable="dimension">
  <HELPTEXT>Status of triaging the bug</HELPTEXT>
  <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
    <LISTITEM value="Approved" />
    <LISTITEM value="Investigate" />
    <LISTITEM value="Differed" />
    <LISTITEM value="No Plans To Resolve" />
  </ALLOWEDVALUES>
</FIELD>
```

Save the file and exit the editor. Now you need to upload the definition back to Team Fundation Server so that it can be used by your team. Open Visual Studio command line and enter this import command:

```
witimport /f "File Path\specialtask.xml" /t "TFS name" /p WITLab
```

When import is done you can use your work item in your project.

Hope this helps!